# Node.js: sending an object from a child process

Tags: node.js, child-process

When sending objects between processes, some features of the object gets lost.

```
// child process sends an object
const dog = new Dog();
process.send(dog);

// in the main process
const child = fork(process.cwd() + '/src/service/child.js');

child.on("message", msg => {
  console.log('is dog?' + msg instanceof Dog)  // will return false.. dogs is now a plain object.
});
```

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Can't. You can only send raw data back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It overrides the object's scope, even if you declare the dog outside, when entering the message event, it's in another scope.

```
child.on("message", msg => {
  console.log('is dog?' + msg instanceof Dog)  // will return false.. dogs is now a plain object.
});
```